# Converting SQL that uses unnest and ilike to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a single table, `books`, with multiple columns, one of the columns `categories` is an array of strings

```
select * from books where exists (select * from (select  unnest(books.categories)) x(categories) where x.categories ilike 'fiction%');
```

Having lots of trouble converting this to SQLAlchemy query string. What I am trying to do is to get all books that has at least a single category starting with the word 'fiction'.

(the simple query below does not work, it is just so you can easily understand what I am trying to achieve with the complex query above)

```
select categories from books where 'fiction%' ilike any(categories);
```

Comment: "_one of the columns categories is an array of strings._" In relational theory that's a bit of an abomination, right? Could I maybe talk you into turning an array of length N into N rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need column valued functions, the following are lines of importance.

```py
column_valued = func.unnest(Book.categories).column_valued()
statement = select(Book).where(select(column_valued).where(column_valued.ilike('fiction%')).exists())
```

The code generates the following sql

```sql
SELECT books.id, books.name, books.categories 
FROM books 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT anon_1 
FROM unnest(books.categories) AS anon_1 
WHERE anon_1 ILIKE %(param_1)s::VARCHAR)
```

Here is a complete example that shows what you want.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, func, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    categories: Mapped[list[str]] = mapped_column(ARRAY(String))

engine = create_engine("connection string")
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    # insert sample test data
    session.add(Book(name='Book 1', categories=['fiction', 'mystery', 'romance', 'adventure']))  # just fiction
    session.add(Book(name='Book 2', categories=['historical', 'horror']))  # no fiction
    session.add(Book(name='Book 3', categories=['fiction historical', 'horror']))  # starts with fiction
    session.add(Book(name='Book 4', categories=['horror']))  # no fiction
    session.add(Book(name='Book 5', categories=['fiction romance', 'horror']))  # starts with fiction
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    column_valued = func.unnest(Book.categories).column_valued()
    statement = select(Book).where(
        select(column_valued).where(column_valued.ilike('fiction%')).exists()
    )

    for i in session.scalars(statement):
        print(i.name)
```

Output

```
Book 1
Book 3
Book 5
```

Books where none of the categories start with `fiction` are not shown here, which I believe is what you want.